# className SerialNow = *((className*)ptr); vs className &SerialNow = *((className*)ptr);

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference, dereference

What is difference between using or not reference when casting pointer to object?

```
void someClass::method() {
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(someTaskHandler,"SerialNowTaskTX",XT_STACK_MIN_SIZE*3,this,4,&taskHandleTX,0); // passing 'this' to task handler
}

void someTaskHandler(void *p) {
    SerialNow_ SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p); // compile but not working properly
    SerialNow_ &SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p); // compile and working
    SerialNow_ *SerialNow = ((SerialNow_*)p); // compile and working but I prefer . over ->
    int A = SerialNow.somethingA;
    SerialNow.somethingB();

    while(1) {
    
    }

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Comment: `SerialNow_ SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p);` makes a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary remark

First, keep in mind that casting `void*` pointers is in C++ a rather dangerous thing, that can be UB if the object pointed to is not compatible with the type you're casting to.

Instead of a C-like cast between parenthesis, prefer a C++ more explicit cast, that shows better the level of danger.  If p would be a polymorphic base type, prefer using the safer [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).  Otherwise use a [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to avoid some common mistakes.  Only in last resort use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), but you'd have to be really sure about what you're doing.

### What's the difference between your statements?

If we'd suppose that p is a valid pointer to a type that is compatible with `SerialNow_` this is the meaning of your different statements:

```
SerialNow_ SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p);
```

The first makes a copy of the the object that is pointed by p. If you later change the content of the object pointed by b, it will have no impact on the object `SerialNow`. Keep in mind that if the object pointed by p is not a `SerialNow_` but a subclass,  [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) might occur.

```
SerialNow_ &SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p);
```

The second creates a reference that refers to the object that is pointed by p. You can use `SerialNow` as if it were an object, but in reality it refers to the same object than the one pointed by p:

```
SerialNow_ *SerialNow = ((SerialNow_*)p);
```

The third creates a pointer to the object that is pointed by p:

The second and the third respect polymorphism.  If the object pointed to by p is not a `SerialNow_` but a subtype, polymorphism will work,  i.e. if you call a virtual function, the one corresponding to the real run-time type of the object will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
SerialNow_ SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p);
```

Here the `void*` `p` is casted(using [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)) to `SerialNow_*`. Next, that resulting `SerialNow_*` is **dereferenced** using the `*operator` resulting in an object of type `SerialNow_`.

Finally, that resulting `SerialNow_` object is used as an **initializer** to initialize the object named `SerialNow` on the left hand side. The newly initialized object `SerialNow` is a copy of the original object. This means that if you make changes to `SerialNow` it won't affect the original object pointed to by `p`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
SerialNow_ &SerialNow = *((SerialNow_*)p);
```

In this case, most of the process is same as case 1 except that this time `SerialNow` is an **alias** for the resulting object. This is different from case one only in that in case 1 the object `SerialNow` on the left hand side was a copy of the original object while here the `SerialNow` on the left hand side is an lvalue reference to the original object. This means that if you make changes to `SerialNow` it will affect the original object pointed to by `p`.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statement:

```
SerialNow_ *SerialNow = ((SerialNow_*)p);
```

Here the `void*` `p` is casted to `SerialNow_*`. But that resulting pointer is **not dereferenced** unlike case 1 and case 2. Thus, here the object named `SerialNow` on the left hand side is initialized from the pointer resulting from the explicit type conversion.

Moreover, `SerialNow` is a copy of the pointer resulting from the explicit type conversion..